# Prove a definition function is inner product

Tags: inner-products

I want prove the formula below be to an inner product:

Given two non-zero vectors $u$ and $v$, with $A$ symmetric and positive definite,

$$\langle u,v\rangle_A:=\langle Au,v\rangle=\langle u,A^Tv\rangle=\langle u,Av\rangle=u^TAv$$

I know we must check $\langle u,v\rangle_A$ satisfies 3 properties:

1. Conjugate symmetric.
2. Linear in the first argument.
3. Positive definite.

But I don't know what to do with matrix. Please help me prove this definition is an inner product.

Answer (score 1):

You prove them by using the properties of matrix multiplication. For instance, for part 2, linearity in the first argument, you want to show that

$$\langle \alpha x + y, z\rangle = \alpha \langle x, z\rangle + \langle y, z\rangle.$$

The left side is
$$(\alpha x + y)^TAz.$$
Since matrix multiplication is linear, you have
$$(\alpha x + y)^TAz=(\alpha x)^TAz + y^TAz = \alpha x^TAz + y^TAz.$$
Finally these two terms correspond to the two inner products
$$\alpha \langle x, z\rangle + \langle y, z\rangle.$$

Does that make sense?